# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request on httpGet with Base Authentication

Tags: java, android, authentication, certificate

I made an application that do a httpGet.

My application uses my own certificate and so the server requires a user login.
For certificate i used [this](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/) tutorial.

For httpGet I've made this implementation:

```
 HttpClient client = new CustClient(getApplicationContext()); // HttpClient that uses my certificates



               // Example send http request
               final String url = "https://ip:port/";// <--in  my implementation i've a right url
               HttpResponse response = null;

               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

               //login
               httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString("root:root".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));

               StringBuilder testo = null;
               try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream contenuto = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contenuto));

                String line;
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 

                    testo.append(line); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Whyen i make **client.execute(httpGet)** response is  *HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request*. Why?
Is correct to authenticate as in my code?

Comment: It looks fine :) My first question is why do not use: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html ? As to your problem I'd try first over regular http and try to intercept request with wireshark or something, and look into servers error log for clues.

Comment: up for your comment! however I'haven't used client.getParams() because in Android HttpClient don't have this method (nor similar methods i think). Fiddler help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the problem was the Authorization header.

We have to use:

```
httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString("root:root".getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Instead of:

```
httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString("root:root".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
```

because the DEFAULT parameter add "CR" line terminator at the end of string and it's uncorrect if you'll use it that header.

Comment: You just saved my day :')

Comment: Awesome answer, this saved my day after hours of no Google help.
Can anyone explain why the two are different?